# ios Evernote API: block executed twice?

Tags: ios, evernote

I'm using the evernote APIs for IOS, and this code will return the number of Notebooks in the account:

```
    EvernoteNoteStore *noteStore = [EvernoteNoteStore noteStore];

    // Traverse Account
    [noteStore listNotebooksWithSuccess:^(NSArray *notebooks) {
        NSLog (@" FIRST Number of notebooks is %d", notebooks.count);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error getting notebooks %@", error);
    }];
```

However the code in the block is executed twice and I got as result two lines like:

2014-02-25 18:58:09.962 EverEX[3884:70b]  FIRST Number of notebooks is 5

2014-02-25 18:58:10.043 EverEX[3884:70b]  FIRST Number of notebooks is 5

That's not right: what am I missing ? it is a really simple piece of code... and there is no reason for the block to execute twice .

Thanks for your help,
                   dom

Comment: is evernotestore calling it twice?

Comment: hmm... where ? the [EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] creates an instance of noteStore, it's not calling it twice ( i think...)

Comment: are you sure your [noteStore listNotebooksWithSuccess:....] is not being called twice? use a breakpoint or a log outside those blocks

Comment: yes, it was the UI to call it twice. Thanks for helping with the troubleshooting !! If you answer officially I will mark your answer as solution. Thanks again !